# Windows Failed Logins SIEM logs - ADFS - User Inactive

Tags: adfs

We are observing multiple windows login failures in SIEM logs. We use SSO, ADFS. Users are inactive, or using normally. User cache cleared. Logs persist.

Comment: Please check the ADFS service and its corresponding application pool in IIS whether its paused/stopped or running.

Comment: This question is not related to programming, please try asking on Server Fault or other more appropriate stack site.

Answer (score 0):

•   Users are logging normally in ADFS trusted SaaS apps through SSO and inactive users are not but still the logs are showing multiple Windows login issue. This surely means that someone is trying to compromise your server and break in your domain environment through series of brute force attacks. Your ADFS WAP server might be exposed to the internet and will be in DMZ outside of firewall protection due to which it got compromised. Please ensure that except port 443 in inbound connection from internet is open and else all the ports are blocked whereas only required ADFS ports are allowed between ADFS and ADFS WAP server else all the ports are blocked for communication. Also, port 445 used for mapping file shares through SMB is not allowed in any way on the ADFS infrastructure.

•   Please check event log IDs with 4625 as they might represent a foreign attacker’s IP address which you should block and blacklist in the firewall immediately. You should also use built in windows firewall and logging settings. The logs will tell you the address of all incoming and outgoing requests. Also, please use the Intrusion detection and defense systems to alert and block and attacks and save your server in future.